# Undefined method '+' for nilclass with rails model (active record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-view-controller, model

I have a simple model with some integer values (I think, I set them to integer in the migration file at least) and I'm just trying to increment them with a member function of the model but when I try to add to them I'm getting the error "Undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)

Any tips here??

```
def take()
    @total -= 1
    User.find(@poster_id).lifetime -= 1
end

def give()
    @total += 1
....
```

nothing more to it really, it's just simple not working. do I need to cast these somehow? I made sure to initialize the values to 0 upon each instantiation of the model class

Comment: Hi, Is total a table column having default value 0?

Comment: @NitinSrivastava yes

Comment: do you realize, that you never define `@total` variable? (whatever it is)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko isn't it defined in the model by activerecord? Outside of the class i'm able to access it with object.total

Comment: @Riptyde4 not as a instance variable. It is a method on self. So if you want to access total it should be self.total or just total.

Comment: @Riptyde4 see the answer with some explanations, let me know if anything is still unclear - i'd extend the answer further

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if `total` is a column in database (and you say it is), then within the instance method of the class you should access it as `total`, not `@total`. Secondly, if you want to update the `total` attribute you should, well, update it :)

```
def take # notice no () - they are optional
  update(total: self.total - 1)
end

def give
  update(total: self.total + 1)
end
```

Analogically with `poster_id` (if, again, it is a column in db) you would do:

```
user = User.find(poster_id) # notice not @poster_id
user.update(lifetime: user.lifetime - 1)
```

Comment: This isn't working right, I have two counters and updating one is overwriting the other to 0. update and update_attribute both result in the same

Comment: I have no idea which counters you are speaking of, but I have answered your question, prior clarified in comments if I understood you right. I explained why you get the exception and how to make work what you showed you were trying to do. You were trying to update the object's attribute - I explained how.  You can ask a new question and be precise in your question text